# Подсветка синтаксиса Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Почему `Visual Studio 2015` выделяет набор знаков `///` другим цветом, не таким как `//`, `///////////` или `/**/`? Есть какое-то специальное применение?

Comment: Не рекомендую использовать Коментарий такого вида /////////// в компиляторе gcc может вызвать Warning или даже не скомпилировать проект.

Comment: Советую установить Tomato Assist. Идеально подсвечивает текст и выдает подсказки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Комментарии вида `///` и `/** */` используются в системах генерации документации, таких как Doxygen.

Answer (score 3):

Используется для автоматической документацией. Вроде XML-документации. [Ссылка на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177246.aspx).